# c# lock on Array vs Index of Array

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Given this code below

```
var array = new object[10];
for(int x = 0;x<array.Length;x++)
    array[x] = new object();


//Lock on Array
lock(array){
    //Do Stuff
}

//Lock on object of array
lock(array[1]){
    //Do Stuff
}

//lock on another object
var o = array[1];
lock(o){
    //Do Stuff
}
```

The first lock statement will lock on the object `array`.

But on the second lock statement, is locking happening on the object at index 1 of the array, or is it also happening on the object `array`?  Another way of asking the question, are the 2nd lock and the 3rd lock the same behavior?

Comment: Do the second lock, and then try each of the first and third to see which is blocked, and which are able to be taken.  Then you'll know which is being locked on.

Comment: I don't think this is really worth a full answer so here it is as a comment: the 2nd and 3rd locks both lock on the same object: the object at array index 1. Do what Servy suggested.

Comment: Alternatively you could just print out `array[1]` and see whether that is the object at index `1` or the whole array.

Comment: There's one object at `array` index 1. In your third sample, you create an additional *variable* that references this same object, but there's still only one object that both `o` and `array[1]` are referencing.

Comment: You must never, never write code like this.  It creates the false impression that the array is now in a magical state that makes it thread-safe.  Nothing like that actually happens.  Always declare a dedicated variable to store the lock state.  Several advantages, one is that you don't have to ask this question.

Comment: Another advantage (re @HansPassant's comment) is that when you create a private variable like `private object _myLock = new object();`, no one outside your class can ever mess with the object you are using as a lock.  Always dedicate a private (non-value-type) object for your locks - it's safer and clearer

Comment: I did what @Servy suggested and just wrote code to test the different scenarios.   Ill post the results in an answer, along with the test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never liked working with `lock` because of the complexity around multithreading.  Answering my question, using the following code here are the results.

Scenrio 2 and 3 are equivalent.  Those lock statements interfere with each other (this is what one would expect by looking at the code).

Scenario 1 doesn't interfere with 2 or 3.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static object o;
        public static object[] array;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            array = new object[10];

            for (int x = 0; x < array.Length; x++)
                array[x] = new object();

            o = array[1];
            var tasks = new Task[100];
            Task t;


            //t = Task.Run(() => lockArray(5000));
            t = Task.Run(() => lockArrayIndex(5000));
            //t = Task.Run(() => lockObject(5000));
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                //tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => lockArray(1000));
                //tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => lockArrayIndex(1000));
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => lockObject(1000));
            }



            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            "done".Dump();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void lockArray(int input)
        {
            //Lock on Array
            lock (array)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(input);
                "Array".Dump();
            }
        }

        private static void lockArrayIndex(int input)
        {
            //Lock on object of array
            lock (array[1])
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(input);
                "Array[1]".Dump();
            }
        }

        private static void lockObject(int input)
        {
            //lock on another object
            lock (o)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(input);
                "o".Dump();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class extenstions
    {
        public static void Dump(this string input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re, "I've never liked...the complexity around multithreading." Yeah, it's hard to get it right, but Your multi-threaded code should either be (A) easier to _read_ than an equivalent single-threaded program, or (B) faster than an equivalent single-threaded program, or (C) both of the above.  If you can't hit one of those targets, then maybe threads are not the right solution to the problem.